Use React component type to populate other properties in an interface
I am working on a project (React + TS) in which I have built a component (in the example below, CardGrid) that accepts an card, does some stuff behind the scenes (removed from the example for simplicity), and then renders the card component in a grid.
The parent component (in the example, SimpleCardGrid) uses CardGrid to render a card component in a grid. CardGrid accepts a component - basically, an uncalled function component (without < and />). Then uses the items array to map each card, along with passing the any "high-level" props (like isLoading ... really, anything that is not item) through componentProps
That component (aka the card) will be constructed the same way as SimpleCard. ICardGrid should be able to read the component and figure out the type for items (an array of ISimpleCardItem, or whatever the type for the card) and componentProps (in this case, it should expect isLoading).
Here is a link to the code on TS Playground and the simplified code:
import * as React from 'react';

type IKey = { key: string };

type ISimpleCardItem = IKey & { text: string };

type IItem<T> = { item: T };

type IIsLoading = { isLoading: boolean };

type ISimpleCard = IItem<ISimpleCardItem> & IIsLoading;

const SimpleCard = ({ item, isLoading}: ISimpleCard) => {
  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading</div>;
  } else {
    return <div>{item.text}</div>;
  }
};

type ICardGrid = {
  component: any;
  items: any[];
  componentProps?: any;
}

const CardGrid = ({ component: Component, items, componentProps }: ICardGrid) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {items?.map((item) => (
        <Component key={item.key} item={item} {...componentProps} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const simpleCardItems: ISimpleCardItem[] = [
  {
    key: 'thisOne',
    text: 'Hello trees',
  },
  {
    key: 'thatOne',
    text: 'Hello sky',
  },
  {
    key: 'theOtherOne',
    text: 'Hello world',
  },
];

const SimpleCardGrid = () => {
  return (
    <CardGrid
      component={SimpleCard}
      items={simpleCardItems}
      componentProps={{
        isLoading: false,
        thisShouldThrowAnError: false,
      }}
    />
  );
};

I am thinking the solution uses Parameters to abstract the props from component. Since Parameters returns an array, getting the 0 index leaves me with ISimpleCard, and then I separate item from all the other props
Something like this:
type CardGridComponentProps = Parameters<typeof SimpleCard>[0]
type CardGridComponentItem = CardGridComponentProps['item'][]
type CardGridComponentOther = Omit<CardGridComponentProps, 'item'>

CardGridComponentItem would be ISimpleCardItem[] and CardGridComponentOther would be { isLoading: boolean }
However, I'm struggling with how to do this using a generic (since SimpleCard is not the real component and this is used with many different card components).
type CardGridComponentProps<C> = Parameters<C>[0]
type CardGridComponentItem<C> = CardGridComponentProps<C>['item']
type CardGridComponentOther<C> = Omit<CardGridComponentProps<C>, 'item'>

type ICardGrid<C> = {
  component: C;
  items: CardGridComponentItem<C>;
  componentProps?: CardGridComponentOther<C>;
}

I've tried applying the suggestions that pop-up in the intelli-sense but can't seem to find a correct solution. Please help - thank you!!!!
